# Redirect Doesn't Allow Me To Go To Other Links

Tags: redirect, meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

I am trying to make a login redirect using the following code:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    if (!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        this.next();
    } else {
        // required by Iron to process the route handler
        this.redirect('/map');
        this.next();
    }
});
```

But, when I login and it successfully redirects me to /maps, I can't click any of my link on my navbar. The link are working fine, but, when I click on them it just redirects me back to /map.

Help will be much appreciated!

Also, here is the github link:

https://github.com/Aggr0vatE/testbasichelp

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I feel like your code is always running each time you load the page, so that if you're logged in you get redirected to /map.

Comment: yeah, that is what I am thinking right now. Just the problem is how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
Router.route('/login',
              { name: 'login' });

var requireLogin = function(){
  if (! Meteor.user() ) {
    this.redirect('login');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except: ['login']});
```

Comment: What am I supposed to redirect for 'somepage'?

Comment: That is the page it will work on. For example, you could have an "admin" where you want your check to be done. I've updated my answer hopefully it's clearer.

Comment: Ok, so the somepage would be like where my code would be checked

Comment: But if I don't have a page like that do I just remove the code? (Sorry, new to iron router >.<)

Comment: Try this:
Router.onBeforeAction(checkLogin, {except: ['login']}); - answer edited

Comment: When you use except: ['login'] it implies you're using a named route, check my edited answer, it contains code that is working for me - Hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88128/discussion-between-alemur-and-stephen-kim).